# Technique for querying date based log data

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql, reporting

I have date based log data for financial records.  Every time the record changes, a new copy of the record is made in the database.
The current method I am using, which I describe below, is both complex and poor performing.  I am dealing with millions of rows and lots of log tables.

The logs are tables in my database that mimic the table we are logging with the addition of a unique log identifier and log date.

For instance, database table RecordLog looks like this:

```
LogId   |  RecordId     | Log Date      | Record Data
--------------------------------------------------------
1   |1      | 2019-07-02    | ...
2   |1      | 2019-05-12    | ...
3   |1      | 2019-03-22    | ...
4   |1      | 2019-01-01    | ...
5   |1      | 2018-08-01    | ...
6   |2      | 2018-01-01    | ...
7   |3      | 2019-01-01    | ...
8   |3      | 2019-02-15    | ...       
9   |3      | 2018-10-15    | ...
```

-The LogId is the log unique id for the RecordLog table, while the RecordId references the unique identifier on the Record table.
-The Record data would mimic the rest of the Record table.

A lot of reporting|analytics occurs based on point in time.  For instance, the user wants know the state of affairs at 2019-01-02

In that case we would get these rows since they are the closest recorded instances <= 2019-01-02:

```
LogId   |  RecordId     | Log Date      | Record Data
--------------------------------------------------------
4   |1      | 2019-01-01    | ...
6   |2      | 2018-01-01    | ...
7   |3      | 2019-01-01    | ...
```

In order to perform these queries now, I am utilizing an inner query.

```
select * from RecordLog where
...
and ...
and ...
and RecordLog.LogId in (
select max(InnerRecordLog.LogId) from RecordLog as InnerRecordLog
where InnerRecordLog.LogDate <= ?
group by InnerRecordLog.RecordId
order by InnerRecordLog.LogDate desc
)
```

One of the challenges is I am using HQL to write these queries which limits my access to some native db options

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has a great extension called `distinct on` which is perfected suited for this:

```
select distinct on (lr.recordid) rl.*
from recordlog rl
where rl.logdate <= '2019-01-02'
order by lr.recordid, rl.logdate desc;
```

`distinct on` (as used here) returns one record per `recordid` (the keys in parentheses).  The specific record is the latest `logdate` record -- but subject to the `where` conditions, of course.

In other databases, the most efficient method is usually a correlated subquery:

```
select rl.*
from recordlog rl
where rl.logdate = (select max(rl2.logdate)
                    from recordlog rl2
                    where rl2.recordid = rl.recordid and
                          rl2.logdate <= '2019-01-02'
                   );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using HQL and "distinct on" can't be used in HQL.  So I was looking for some non db native solutions.  Also, although "distinct on" simplifies the writing of the query, I don't think it actually improves the performance.

Comment: I would expect using distinct on to be significantly faster than your query, but if you can't use it in HQL, then I guess it's not going to work for you.

Comment: @springcorn . . . Your question is tagged Postgres which is why I provided this answer.

Comment: Gordon I guess I misrepresented the question a bit.  You're answer is a good one, I just don't know how to do it in hql